# Reading material on Random Walk on S_n using Transpositions

Tags: random-walk

I am from an engineering background and I wanted to get hold of some very basic reading material on Random Walk on $S_n$ (symmetric group on n letters) using Transpositions. Could someone suggest some?

Comment: I'm guessing by $S_n$ you mean the symmetric group on $n$ letters?

Comment: Yes. I will add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05387) is a good reference for the general theory (if I may be so bold). There are a couple of remarks on random walks driven by transpositions on pages 16 and 49.

For a fuller treatment see

- P. Diaconis. *Group Representations in Probability and Statistics*.
  IMS: Hayward, CA, 1988.